# How to broadcast screen of an Android device to another Android device?

Tags: android, broadcast, mirror

I want to make an app that broadcasts (mirrors) the screen of the Android you are using to another Android device. I have two requirements:

1. broadcast screen of an android device to another
2. broadcast the screen of an Android device to more than 10 devices.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: How many developers are on your team, and how many years do you have to write this? IMHO, this is **not** a suitable project for an inexperienced solo developer.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You can start your research with Google Cast SDK.

Comment: actually i wanna make an app such that i am drawing something on my screen and the other user is able to view that in real time do u how i can do that